# Text recognition in multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, count, textbox, character, multiple-columns

I just wanna ask how can I recognize a character in multiple textboxes.
I can show you how do I mean it. Here is an image of the thing

[image]

You can see column which is signed with character "T". there are only "+" and "-" characters. I need to count "+" and "-" but i don't know how to count them from multiple textboxes.

I need to do it automatically and not like textbox1.text, textbox2.text etc. Is there a method which I can use. The number of rows is not stable.. sometimes there will be 7 rows or 10 rows... So I need some automatic function.

Comment: Are you really talking about  'character recognition' (as in OCR)? Sounds as if you have access to the textboxes and their properties? Please explain !

Comment: I need to recognize if in textbox is "+" or "-" .. and if there is "+" then i nneed to save it into some kind if int. so if there are 3 pluses, the int which i declared before shows me "3". The same with minuses...i hope you'll understand

Comment: If you have access to the TextBox you can access its Text property like e.g. this: if (aTextBox.Text.Contains("+") ).." If you need help accessing array of controls, please correct the question!

Comment: Ok i found a solution... i used List of textboxes and used foreach to access text in each textbox... so you can take this question for answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys.. i found a solution... for those who want to do the same thing I recommend to use something like this

```
List<TextBox> ListofPluses = new List<TextBox>();
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox1);
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox2);
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox3);
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox4);
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox5);
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox6);
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox7);
ListofPluses.Add(Tbox8);
```

Where  Tbox1-8 are textboxes :)